# Multiple redirects in .htacces (http to https; .html to .php; index to /)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For re-directing all requests without “www.” or with “http:” I was using the following .htaccess settings since activating SSL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R=301,L]
```

I now noticed that my former redirections of index.php to / don’t work anymore, if the requested URL is http.

Also, I now need to change current .html files (half of my website) to .php and add this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

I would like to use as little rewrites as possible to maximize SEO effects, but I got stuck trying around. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After trying around for some more hours, I think I came to an elegant solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)index\.php/?$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)index\.html/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
# index.php or index.html are sent to https://www.domain.tld/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.php [R=301,L]
# .html is changed to .php and additionally redirected to https://www.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
# Everthing not redirected before, gets an additional www. and/or is redirected to https.
```

I'm happy about comments and recommendations to improve further, if neccessary. Hope this is helpful to anyone.